# ASP.NET code generation links and images for forums

Tags: html, code-generation

I will be providing my users with code generated as links or images to embbed on different websites or on their personal.

Ok so normal generated code would look something like:

```
<a href=""></a>
<img src=""></img>
```

And this would work on any website where you can post html or on users personal site.

But what to generate when user would like to post this kind of code generated to forums?
I know there isn't any universal tags for ALL forums for images and links, but what tags are used on most of forums?

I saw tags like:

```
[URL="foo"][/URL]
[url:foo][/url]
```

So the question is what to generate when this kind of code would be used to be posted in forums, or to provide users with src and href links and post some kind of tutorial?

Comment: I'll never understand why people want to invent an alternate html syntax, when the current can't be better.

Comment: @Hari I'm not trying to invent anything, I just want to find out what is the best way to format code for user that wants to post that code to forum.

Comment: @Hari I'm not sure you understand his question, he is not trying to invent a markup language, he is trying to create a program that generates markup in an already existing language for a forum/bulletin board application.

Comment: ok, I apologize, my remark was uncalled for.

Comment: @Hari No problem, btw I totally agree with your first comment, If all forums used plain html syntax I wouldn't have to format html code to forum markup languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, BBCode is the most common markup for use in bulletin board/forum software.  If I were to choose one to support for this type of app, that is the one I would pick.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode

Having said that, each forum is different, so it would probably be worth your while to a) find out which forum(s) your users most commonly post on, and support those forums' markup formats, and b) make it very clear what type of forum markup they are generating so you aren't helping them violate the posting guidelines of their favorite forum.

Comment: Oh silly me, I didn't even know there is more then one standardized markup language for forums, I always thought every other variation was kind of customized BBCode, thank you for pointing me to article. I guess i will just add another drop down box with BBCode as default so my users can choose format.My app clearly states: code will be gerenarted as images or links so no worry there. Thanks agian!